# Android Calendar "Grid of Dates"

Tags: android, controls, calendar

I am looking for an Android open source Calendar control which displays the full month in a grid, much like a real printed-on-paper calendar. It's for an app to show special days.

Like this from my iPhone version we are porting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/ancal/
that is an open source android calendar
very very nice

Comment: I could not get the full source code from the above link. How to get full project? or Whether it is available like third-party lib?

Comment: i get project source code using svn. but it was error-full in eclipse and cant run (using android 2.3.3 and 4.0) :(